# AngularJS Not Updating Total in Dynamic Table

Tags: angularjs, dynamic

I am trying to total all prices and quantities when I add a an item to my table. I cannot get the total to refresh.  Can someone see an error in my code?

```
$scope.updateTotals = [];
function ExampleCtrl ($scope){
    $scope.people = [
        {number: '1', title: 'Tom Sawyer', author: 'Mark Twain', price: '28', quantity: '2', action: 'xx'},
        {number: '2', title: 'Alice\'s Adventure in Wonderland', author: 'Lewis Carroll', price: '17.00', quantity: '2', action: 'xx'},
        {number: '3', title: 'The Old Man and the Sea', author: 'Ernest Hemingway', price: '17', quantity: '1', action: 'xx'}

    ];


$scope.addPerson = function (){
    var person = {
        number: $scope.number,
        title: $scope.title,
        author: $scope.author,
        price: $scope.price,
        quantity: $scope.quantity,
        action: $scope.action

    };

    $scope.people.push( person );
};

$scope.removePerson = function (index){
    $scope.people.splice( index, 1 );


};

$scope.totPrice = function (){
    var totPrice = 0;
    var values = [$scope.people]
    angular.forEach(values, function(price, quantity) {
        totPrice += (price * quantity)
    });
    return totPrice;
};
$scope.totQty = function (){
    var totQty = 0;
    angular.forEach(
        $scope.people.quantity, function (quantity){
            totQty += (
                $scope.people.quantity * $scope.people.title
                );
            return totQty; }
    );



};


}
```

Comment: You can use [`$watchGroup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) to monitor all the quantities and update the total when one of them changes. (Incidentally, it's rather confusing to use a variables called `people` and `person` to refer to products.)

Comment: why are you doing `$scope.people.quantity * $scope.people.title` while you're iterating on `$scope.people.quantity`? you're trying to do math against an array or object?

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.updateTotals = [];
function ExampleCtrl ($scope){
    $scope.people = [
        {number: '1', title: 'Tom Sawyer', author: 'Mark Twain', price: '28', quantity: '2', action: 'xx'},
        {number: '2', title: 'Alice\'s Adventure in Wonderland', author: 'Lewis Carroll', price: '17.00', quantity: '2', action: 'xx'},
        {number: '3', title: 'The Old Man and the Sea', author: 'Ernest Hemingway', price: '17', quantity: '1', action: 'xx'}

    ];


$scope.addPerson = function (){
    var person = {
        number: $scope.number,
        title: $scope.title,
        author: $scope.author,
        price: $scope.price,
        quantity: $scope.quantity,
        action: $scope.action

    };

    $scope.people.push( person );

 //call calculate total here
 $scope.totPrice()
};

$scope.removePerson = function (index){
    $scope.people.splice( index, 1 );
 //call calculate total here
 $scope.totPrice()


};

$scope.totPrice = function (){
    var totPrice = 0;
    var values = [$scope.people]
    angular.forEach(values, function(price, quantity) {
        totPrice += (price * quantity)
    });
    return totPrice;
};
$scope.totQty = function (){
    var totQty = 0;
    angular.forEach(
        $scope.people.quantity, function (quantity){
            totQty += (
                $scope.people.quantity * $scope.people.title
                );
            return totQty; }
    );



};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, totPrice calculates the total price, and addPerson is called from your HTML-Script as a ng-click event?

Have you already tried to execute:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

To say angular you got changes?

How do you show the "total-price" in your HTML?

Better variante would be:

```
  $scope.totPrice = function (){
    var totPrice = 0;
    var values = [$scope.people]
    angular.forEach(values, function(price, quantity) {
        totPrice += (price * quantity)
    });
    $scope.totalPrice = totPrice;
};

<span ng-bind="totalPrice">
```

Rather store the totalPrice in a variable and bind it.